# Spring Data R2DBC master slave configuration

Tags: spring, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Is there a way in Spring Data R2DBC to setup a second datasource as slave read-only ?

Comment: Here's some reading material: https://blog.pchudzik.com/201911/read-from-replica/

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to configure multi R2dbc connections in the same application.

Check my example project: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/multi-r2dbc-connectionfactorie